# JOIN Optimization with CASE expressions in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization, inner-join

The 2 tables below will pull a world of data from details_2 table but will join to the fields based on different reason coded in #exceptions table.

Is there a better way to write the below query?

```sql
Select
a.Fieldname1,
a.Fieldname2,
a.fieldname3
from 
#Exceptions a, [DETAILS_2] b
where 

(case when a.REASON_CD = 'LOBMKT' then CONCAT(a.LOB_CD,a.GEO_MARKET) end = concat(b.LOB_CD,b.GEO_MARKET)) or
(case  when a.REASON_CD = 'LOB' then a.LOB_CD end  = b.LOB_CD) or
(case  when a.REASON_CD = 'CAT' then a.CTRCT_CAT_CD end  = b.CTRCT_CAT_CD) or
(case  when a.REASON_CD = 'LOBST' then CONCAT(a.LOB_CD,a.[derived_GEO_MARKET]) end = concat(b.LOB_CD,b.GEO_MARKET))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. And, you have a comma-join without any sort of join criterion.

Comment: Please add sample data and desired output.

Comment: It seems you are unnecessarily using CONCAT(). Just a wild guess without seeing sample data and desired output.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) & [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 2):

I think I would go for this, howver not able to test anything without sample data and desired output like Cetin also mentiones.

I would go for the UNION ALL, as the data should be unique in all different statements. So SQL does not need to verify that (with costing more CPU)

```
SELECT
     a.Fieldname1,
     a.Fieldname2,
     a.fieldname3
FROM #Exceptions a
     JOIN [DETAILS_2] b ON a.REASON_CD = 'LOBMKT'
                           AND a.LOB_CD = b.LOB_CD
                           AND a.GEO_MARKET = b.GEO_MARKET
UNION ALL
SELECT
     a.Fieldname1,
     a.Fieldname2,
     a.fieldname3
FROM #Exceptions a
     JOIN [DETAILS_2] b ON a.REASON_CD = 'LOB'
                           AND a.LOB_CD = b.LOB_CD
UNION ALL
SELECT
     a.Fieldname1,
     a.Fieldname2,
     a.fieldname3
FROM #Exceptions a
     JOIN [DETAILS_2] b ON a.REASON_CD = 'CAT'
                           AND a.CTRCT_CAT_CD = b.CTRCT_CAT_CD
UNION ALL
SELECT
     a.Fieldname1,
     a.Fieldname2,
     a.fieldname3
FROM #Exceptions a
     JOIN [DETAILS_2] b ON a.REASON_CD = 'LOBST'
                           AND a.LOB_CD = b.LOB_CD
                           AND a.[derived_GEO_MARKET] = b.GEO_MARKET;
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is sargable and easier to understand what it is doing:

```
Select a.Fieldname1, a.Fieldname2, a.fieldname3
from #Exceptions a
inner join [DETAILS_2] b on a.LOB_CD = b.LOB_CD and a.GEO_MARKET = b.GEO_MARKET
where a.REASON_CD = 'LOBMKT'
UNION ALL
Select a.Fieldname1, a.Fieldname2, a.fieldname3
from #Exceptions a
inner join [DETAILS_2] b on a.LOB_CD = b.LOB_CD
where a.REASON_CD = 'LOB'
UNION ALL
Select a.Fieldname1, a.Fieldname2, a.fieldname3
from #Exceptions a
inner join [DETAILS_2] b on a.CTRCT_CAT_CD = b.CTRCT_CAT_CD
where a.REASON_CD = 'CAT'
UNION ALL
Select a.Fieldname1, a.Fieldname2, a.fieldname3
from #Exceptions a
inner join [DETAILS_2] b on a.LOB_CD = b.LOB_CD and a.[derived_GEO_MARKET] = b.GEO_MARKET
where a.REASON_CD = 'LOBST'
```

Answer (score 0):

(Beware you are doing a cross join)

```
SELECT a.Fieldname1,
       a.Fieldname2,
       a.fieldname3
FROM #Exceptions a,
     [DETAILS_2] b
WHERE (
          a.REASON_CD = 'LOBMKT'
          AND a.LOB_CD = b.LOB_CD
          AND a.GEO_MARKET = b.GEO_MARKET
      )
      OR
      (
          a.REASON_CD = 'LOB'
          AND a.LOB_CD = b.LOB_CD
      )
      OR
      (
          a.REASON_CD = 'CAT'
          AND a.CTRCT_CAT_CD = b.CTRCT_CAT_CD
      )
      OR
      (
          a.REASON_CD = 'LOBST'
          AND a.LOB_CD = b.LOB_CD
          AND a.[derived_GEO_MARKET] = b.GEO_MARKET
      );
```